# grab CSS value with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am hoping that someone can help me with this regex, I need to grab `test2 and everything between { }`

```
    .test1 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #42bf32; font-size: 14px; }
.test2 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #42bf32; font-size: 14px; }
.test3 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #42bf32; font-size: 14px; }
```

I am using ASP and Javascript

I have a feeling the regex would be something like this `test2.replace(/\.test(.*?)\{(.*?)\}/ig, '.test3');`

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks to Steward it now works fine `.replace(/.test *{[^}]*/ig, '');`

Comment: why are you trying to grab the css w/ regex? there's probably a better solution to what you're doing, then to use regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test2[[:space:]]*{[^}]*}
```

But you should probably use a real css parser instead.

Comment: Thanks Stuart i have chaged ut to .replace(/.test *{[^}]*/ig, ''); but it leaves the last } in the code. any idea why?

Comment: lol wait I think I see what I have done wrong .replace(/.test *{[^}]*}/ig, ''); let me try it like this

Comment: You can format your code by indenting it with 4 spaces (look at the box to the right when editing an answer).

Comment: No CSS comments like `.test2 { font-family: Arial /* }{ */ }` ?

Comment: hi Wrikken nice idea to include comments :-) I have not comments in my styles - I am building an online css editor - with basic functionality...

Answer (score 1):

```
/\.test2\s*\{.*\}/
```

You also might want to look into other RegExp methods, `replace` may not be what you want.  Specifically, you should check out `test()` and `exec()`.  See [Javascript Kit's Regex Tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev3.shtml).